# Можно ли отличить нажатую кнопку на физической клавиатуре или мышке, от эмулированной?

Tags: c#, windows, .net, winapi, vb.net

Речь про глобальное нажатие клавиш на клавиатуре или мышке а не для конкретного окна в Windows.
Можно ли как то программно отловить и если да, какие способы можно отловить а какие нет?

Comment: В теории можно, но дял этого придется минуя Win API обращаться к самой клавиатуре как HID устройству.

Comment: @aepot то есть в теории античит, на практике это может сделать, ну например банально отслеживать использование макросов?. Речь не про читы, речь про макросы автоматически нажимающие нужные клавиши

Comment: Все возможно. Вопрос - какой ценой? Никто не говорил, что это сделать легко.

Comment: а когда считыватель штрих-кодов, представившись компьютеру как контроллер клавиатуры, посылает сообщения о якобы введённой строке текста (содержащей штрих-код), это считается «нажатием кнопок на физической клавиатуре», или «эмулированной»?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin это считается вводом с физического HID устройства. Все живое в винде отправляет кнопки через WinAPI будь то даже клава. Автора как я понял интересует, участвовало ли железо в воде, или же софтина отправила ввод в систему. Чтобы это узнать, надо вкрутиться в девайс и отслеживать его состояние. При чем девайсы разные бывают.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42799145/12888024 думаю речь про чтение Raw Input

Comment: На 100% надёжно - увы никак, некоторые современные высокобюджетные ММОРПГ для этих целей даже пилят свои дрова безопасности, который пользователь должен ставить (автоматически ставится конечно), но даже такое обходят.